Interactive map with R shiny
I have developed a Shiny web application that displays an interactive map where you can select a weather station and a year, and then it generates an Excel file containing the meteorological data for the selected station. However, I am encountering issues: the map takes a long time to load, and when i select a station and a year and try to export the data, the interface closes and the software displays an error stating that the "annee" argument is missing, with no default value. please help me to solve that problem.
Here is my code:
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(shinybusy)
library(readr)


##---------------------------------------------------------------
##                          Interface                          --
##---------------------------------------------------------------
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  add_busy_spinner(spin = "radar", margins = c(10, 20)),
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(id='nomappli',top = 0, left=70,img(src = 'EDFMeteostat.png',height = 68.35, width = 397.5),
                downloadButton("dl_aide", "Aide"),
                downloadButton("dl_rapport", "Rapport Ms-Pro")),
  absolutePanel(id='parametres',class='panel panel-default' ,top = 10, right = 10,
                width = "auto", fixed = TRUE, draggable = TRUE,
                p(),
                p(strong("Extraction de données météos au pas horaire")),
                pickerInput("pays", label = "Pays", # Menu déroulant sélection pays
                            choices = df_conversion_ISO_dispo[[3]],
                            selected = "France Metropole - FR Metro",
                            options = list(`live-search` = TRUE)),
                checkboxInput("chexkbox_recent", label = "Avec anciennes stations (arretées depuis plus d'un an)", value = FALSE), 
                pickerInput("annee", label = "Choix d'année d'extraction", 
                            choices = c(year(Sys.Date()),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(1)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(2)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(3)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(4)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(5)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(6)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(7)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(8)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(9)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(10)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(11)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(12)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(13)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(14)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(15)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(16)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(17)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(18)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(19)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(20)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(21)),
                                        year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(22))
                            ),
                            selected = year(Sys.Date() %m-% years(1))
                ),
                p(),
                p(strong('Calcul des DJU :')),
                sliderInput("slider_chauf", label = "Température de consigne chauffage (°C)", min = 15, max = 25, value = 18),
                sliderInput("slider_clim", label = "Température de consigne climatisation (°C)", min = 15, max = 25, value = 18),
                actionButton("export", label = "Exporter"),
                p(),
                
  )
)


##---------------------------------------------------------------
##                          Server.                            --
##---------------------------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  valeurs <- reactiveValues()
  
  ##------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ##  Filtration des stations à afficher en fonction du pays sélectionné  --
  ##------------------------------------------------------------------------
  filteredData <- reactive({
    df_filtr_stations <- df_stations
    if (input$chexkbox_recent == FALSE){
      df_filtr_stations  <- filter(df_filtr_stations , inventory.hourly.end >Sys.Date() %m-% years(1))
    }
    if (input$pays == 'France Metropole - FR Metro'){
      filter(df_filtr_stations , country == 'FR', timezone == 'Europe/Paris')
    } else {
      l<-which(df_conversion_ISO_dispo[[3]]==input$pays) 
      filter(df_filtr_stations, country == df_conversion_ISO_dispo[l,2])
      return(filter(df_filtr_stations, country == df_conversion_ISO_dispo[l,2]))
    }
  })
  ##---------------------------------------------------------------
  ##                        Click station                        --
  ##---------------------------------------------------------------
  observe({
    click<-input$map_marker_click
    if(is.null(click))
      return()
    valeurs$id <- click$id
  })
  ##---------------------------------------------------------------
  ##                            CARTE                            --
  ##---------------------------------------------------------------
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = 2.2137, lat = 46.2276, zoom = 6) %>%
      addMarkers(data = stations,
                 lng = ~location.longitude,
                 lat = ~location.latitude,
                 label = ~name.en,
                 popup = ~popuptext,
                 layerId = ~id)
  })
  ##----------------------------------------------------------------
  ##                  Chargement du fichier meteo                 --
  ##----------------------------------------------------------------  
  data_meteo <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file
    if (is.null(inFile)){
      return(NULL)
    }
    df_meteo <- fread(inFile$datapath)
    return(df_meteo)
  })
  
  
  ##----------------------------------------------------------------
  ##                  Click du bouton "exporter"                  --
  ##----------------------------------------------------------------
  observeEvent(input$export, {
    if (is.null(valeurs$id)){
      showModal(modalDialog(
        "Pas de station sélectionnée, cliquez sur une station pour la sélectionner.",
        footer = modalButton("Retour"),
      ))
      return()
    }
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = NULL,
      p(strong("1 - Cliquer sur ce lien :",
               a(nom_lien(valeurs$id))
      )),
      p("2 - Si le lien n'a pas fonctionné, copiez le lien dans votre navigateur internet"),
      footer = NULL,
    ))
  })
}


##----------------------------------------------------------------
##                            Application                       --
##----------------------------------------------------------------
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
> > 


Welcome to SO. Please produce a minimal reproducible example, so that we have a better chance at helping you.
